# C++: call a function using callback mechanism

Tags: c++, boost

I am very new to boost functions and the callback mechanism in C++. I couldn't find a way to use the callback mechanism in the following situation:

On component C1, I have function `f1`. On another component C2, I have function `f2`. In the normal flow, `f1()` is called before `f2()`. I need to call `f2()` before `f1()`, but I have difficulties since they are implemented on different software components (but in the same local repository) with the logical rules: C2 knows about C1, but C1 does not know about C2.

Theoretically a possible solution is to use a boost function pointer `p2` to `f2()`, then to create a function. Below I am trying to emulate the component C2 by a server. The code belongs to the component C1, where I am trying to call a function from the server(C2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <list>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace  std;
using namespace boost;

struct server
{
void func(int i, char a)
{
    printf(" %d %c \n", i,a);
}
};

typedef boost::function<void(server*, int,char)> my_func_t;

int main()
{

    my_func_t var = &server::func;
    server s;

    var(&s , 10, 'a');
}
```

The output is 10 a, as it should be.

I try to use the boost function since there are two software components: C1 and C2. C1 does not know about C2, but C2 does know about C1 (logical convention). The problem is to call from C1 a function from C2, so I cannot do in the standard way to just create an object and call the method.

Is this the good way of doing it? If so, I have to update the question.

Thank you a lot !

Comment: I'm confused.  The code being in a namespace doesn't affect your ability to call functions in any order you deem appropriate.

Comment: I'm also confused. What does this have to do with callbacks or boost?

Comment: Ditto. Maybe provide some sample code to show what you have, and what you want to do.

Comment: Perhaps it would be beneficial to just squarely follow SO guidelines and post a small self-contained compilable example that demonstrates the problem. The pseudocode can be OK but in this case it is not really clear what it's supposed to do, or what's wrong with it.

Comment: Thank you all. I updated the question with a better description.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest case may just be to wrap the calls, assuming you need to be able to switch between normal and non-normal arbitrarily at runtime:

```
void call_it(bool normal)
{
    if(normal)
    {
        f1();
        f2();
    }
    else
    {
        f2();
        f1();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I updated the question with a better description.